# Is there any Stack Exchange site for buying used (physical) programming books?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there any Stack Exchange site for exchanging/reselling used programming books? I wanted to buy a certain book few months ago, and missed a moment when a cheap used copy was available. However, somebody, somewhere might be willing to sell used copy.

Is there any Stack Exchange site for this kind of thing?

Comment: Q&A isn't really a great format for sales.

Comment: @TCPMAN.EXE: Why? It would be pretty similar to existing format: Q: "lookin for item X". A: "offering item X for $xyz". Still, i'm not exactly looking for sales stackexchange, just for a place where I could find somebody who could sell a copy.

Comment: Part of the goal on SE is to not have a bunch of cruft content (eg. Where someone was buying or selling something in the distant past and it is no longer relevant to anyone.)

Comment: @SigTerm - So the answer will become obsolete once the answerer has sold the book?

Comment: Craig?  Is that you?

Answer (score 9):

The goal of Stack Exchange network is to get the solutions of your problems or give the solutions to anyone's problem. Stack Exchange network is not an online shopping website where you can buy or sale anything. So such site does not exist and will not be created in future.

Comment: Someone should create an online auction site anyone can buy/sell on. They would make so much money!

Comment: I thought one was in place called e-bay?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - http://www.olx.com??

Comment: @mehow: ebay has very limited selection of books - they rarely appear at all.

Comment: @SigTerm well, amazon? not an auction but still you can buy second hand books much cheaper. I personally bought a few!

Comment: @mehow: Amazon has plenty of books, but they have minor problem with international shipments. Their shipping rates are fairly high, and every time you have to sift to 20 sellers to find only two that ship internationally. In other words, amazon works for books, but it is kinda last-resort solution. And I've been unable to find better alternatives.

Comment: And anyway, @sigterm, Stack Exchange isn't here to run such a service. They don't sell waffles, do unicorn-hunting safaris, or manufacture LED monitors, either... despite how related those are to programming. (Especially the unicorn thing)

Comment: @SigTerm And you think a Q&A based system for selling books would be *less* chaotic than that?

Comment: @RichardTingle: I think that in community full of programmers it'll be easier to find somebody with a copy of a book you want. It should also be possible to get a better deal.

Comment: @AndrewBarber: Good programming books are better/more useful than unicorns.

Comment: @SigTerm I disagree, but still, being ebay is not what Stack Exchange is here for.

Comment: @SigTerm you gravely underestimate the power of unicorns.  But the point has been made, no selling of books here, end-of-story.

Comment: @SigTerm: unicorns aren't obsolete the day they're printed.

Comment: @Wooble Unicorns aren't pri... ooooh, I see what you did, there! I think... ;)